# Get last document in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the last document in a MongoDB collection.
The following works in the Mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Results in the last object like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62c8817075c9400469b1fc3a"), "token" : "135e53ebb05aa2b6055513843cb8e0dca1", "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-07-08T19:11:44.730Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-07-08T19:11:44.730Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

But this does not work in my Express app:

```
 const last = FM_Model.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
 console.log('Last Token from MONGODB here -> ', last)
```

In the code above the console.log returns a very long object related to the collection itself, but not the document I want.

I have tried other variations but nothing has worked so far. If anyone can give me any ideas of what I am missing that would be great.

Comment: Why can't you just use findOne()? Something like `db.collection.findOne({$query: {}, $orderby: {$natural : -1}})`

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that one, but I'll give it another shot. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelHager The `findOne` query you suggested actually returns the first document.

Comment: Did you try 1 instead of -1

Comment: @windowsill yes, it was the first thing I thought too. Still returns the first document.

Comment: Maybe Mongoose doesn't let you do this. Of course it can't be used for any production purposes anyways because `> This ordering is an internal implementation feature, and you should not rely on any particular ordering of the documents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns an array. But there is an better version with `.findOne` wich return the result or `undefined`

```
FM_Model.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'createdAt' : -1 } })
```

With `-1` you get the oldest element, wich is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try

db.collection.find().sort({'_id':-1}).limit(1)

First revert the order then get the first one

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sorting on the _id field as it's indexed by default: [reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/#:%7E:text=Default%20_id%20Index,index%20on%20the%20_id%20field.). Or you could sort by the createdAt if the field has a descending order index.

```
const last = await FM_Model.findOne({}).sort({ _id: -1 });
```

More about MongoDB indexing can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/)